# Cron job does not run, but command is OK when run manually at shell

Tags: shell, cron, scrapy

I have the following entry in my crontab:

```
0,30 7-18 * * 1-5 cd /path/to/scrapers && scrapy crawl funny_quotes  &>> $(date "+/home/foobar/logs/\%Y\%m\%d.funny.log"
```

This entry is supposed to run every half hour, on weekdays and append the output to the log file each time it's run. I have tested the syntax online, using [this handy tool](http://cron.schlitt.info/), and the syntax is correct.

However, the job doesn't get run. What's worse, the log file is  created (but has no contents - file size 0), so I have no diagnostic information to go by.

The command `cd /path/to/scrapers && scrapy crawl funny_quotes` runs perfectly when I type it at the command, and there is copious amounts of information output to the console, from scrapy.

Why does the cronjob fail to run sccessfully - and why is nothing being piped to the log file?

Comment: I assume the "funny_quotes" file is in /path/to/scrapers. In that case, have you tried this? `scrapy crawl /path/to/scrapers/funny_quotes  &>> $(date "+/home/foobar/logs/\%Y\%m\%d.funny.log"`

Comment: `&>>` is Bash 4 syntax, and I'm wondering if your cron job runs with Bash 4. Try with good old-fashioned `2>> path 1>&2` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your cron logs

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

I am sure you are getting error something like `scrapy - command not found` or something similar.

To fix it, do this

Enter and copy the output of `echo $PATH` from shell.

And then open `crontab -e`

At the very top of file, write `PATH=YOUR_COPIED_CONTENTS`

And that should work.